# Issue regarding SWT variables declaration order

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm developing a simple Java application with SWT for the user interface.
Everything works fine, but I'm having some issues with the variables declaration order (it's my first SWT application).

I have two buttons, called btnStop and btnStart, with a SelectionAdapter event attached to them.

This is the behaviour they should have:

- When I click on the button btnStart, its event has to set btnStard disabled and btnStop enabled;
- Same goes for the button btnStop: another event has to disable btnStop itself and enable btnStart.

The fact is: if I declare btnStop before btnStart, the former's event cannot set the latter disabled and vice versa since Eclipse says that the one of the two variables (depending on the declaration order) has not been initialized.

Here's part of the code:

```
 final Button btnStop = new Button(shlFinalFantasyXiv, SWT.NONE);

    btnStop.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            Check.keepPinging = false;          
            comboServer.setEnabled(true);
            btnStart.setEnabled(true); // <- ERROR HERE
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });
    btnStop.setBounds(357, 106, 75, 25);
    btnStop.setText("Stop");

final Button btnStart = new Button(shlFinalFantasyXiv, SWT.NONE);

    btnStart.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        // some stuff
        }
```

If you have any advice, it'd be very appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't set up the selection listeners until after you have declared both buttons:

```
final Button btnStop = new Button(shlFinalFantasyXiv, SWT.NONE);
// set text, layout

final Button btnStart = new Button(shlFinalFantasyXiv, SWT.NONE);
// set text, layout

btnStop.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    // code
}

btnStart.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    // some stuff
}
```

By the way learn about using [Layouts](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) to lay out your controls. Using `setBounds` means things will be messed up if the font used is changed.

Comment: Great! Now it works! I thought that I had to define the method immediately after the button declaration, but I was wrong. I'll also take a look at the tutorial, thanks for the help.

Comment: You can add (and remove) listeners whenever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You will need one global ActionListener for both of your Buttons. It determines with an IF wich Button was pressed and will activate one and disable the other.

Have a look at this turorial where the concept is illustrated in the chapter "Multiple sources": http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/swingevents/

You´re using SWT, but the concepts are the same within swing.